# Null pointer exception in writing excel using java poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to write a java class that computes the age of the person by getting his/her birth year on excel file. I was successful in computing it and displaying the age on console using `System.out.print(age);`, however, I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` on `cell.setCellValue(age);`
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
int age;
for(int i = 0; i < birthdate.size(); i++){
    String bday = birthdate.get(i).toString();
    String y = bday.substring(7, 11);
    age = year - Integer.parseInt(y);
    cell = sheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(5);
    cell.setCellValue(age);
    System.out.print(cell + " \t ");
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the value of cell?Could you please debug?

Comment: You need to check if the cell exists and if it doesn't exist you need to create it

Comment: @Ankit, cell has no value. i will get the year from birthdate cell, and compute the age and pass it on age cell.

Comment: I hadn't worked with apache poi yet so I may be wrong (which is why I don't want to post it as answer, nor vote to close as duplicate of since canonical question doesn't have solution for this case), but based on `getCell(int)` documentation https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int) it can return null if cell is not defined (I am guessing that it means that when cell doesn't have value). If that is the case then try using overloaded version `getCell(int cellnum, Row.MissingCellPolicy policy)` with `getCell(5, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);`

Comment: @Pshemo you're awesome! how can I mark your answer? thanks!

Comment: You can't "accept" comments as answers, and I don't want to post it as such since I am not sure if this is best or even proper approach of handling this problem (since I am not familiar yet with POI library). But feel free to post your own answer which code you are using (if you are sure that it is working as you intended).

Comment: Never mind, I found duplicate, so there is not even need to post another answer.